# Is there any way to conditionally disable Publisher Actions on Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I would like to be able to conditionally enable/disable specific Publisher Actions on a record based on some execution logic. Is there any way to do that? I haven't been able to find any way to have a Publisher Action be displayed but disabled.

My current best solution is to simply take the user to a screen which explains why they cannot perform the action they've attempted, but that is definitely sub-optimal behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do that for the moment. You can close by javascript the page but can't disable or hide the button.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using different record types + page layouts.
Based on your execution logic, you could switch a record type to another one and then, on the page layout linked to that record type you can decide which publisher actions you want to show.

But of course, if this would lead you to creating tons of record types / page layouts, it could quickly become a maintenance issue so be cautious with this approach as well.